# How do you disable the default rescue to user-friendly static pages in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently my development environment produces the errors on the page when a runtime error happens but when I'm on the test/production server it produces the user-friendly errors. I want the actual errors in the test site. Is there someplace to disable this?

Thanks

Comment: You could just look at your production log files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a config setting.  Try setting

config.consider_all_requests_local       = true

in /config/environments/production.rb
and /config/environments/test.rb

As holder points out you should be careful about doing this in public environments as it can expose sensitive information about your application.

Comment: It exposes application internals and stack traces to user and is thus really dangerous most of the time. Thus it should only be enabled in environments which are not run on production systems. Typically you don't want this enabled in the production env.